# 'He is rumored that he is writing a new book' - why is this wrong?

Tags: syntax, exam-questions

I came across the following sentence in a test and it is wrong answer so there cannot be a sentence in this structure. Could you explain to me why?

> He is rumored that he is writing a new book.

Comment: Sounds odd. I'd say “It is rumored that he is writing a new book,” or “He is rumored to be writing a new book.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because *is rumored* takes a choice of frames:

> It is rumored that X is Y.

and, by [subject raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_%28linguistics%29),

> X is rumored to be Y.

Your sentence is of the form

> *X is rumored that X is Y.

but that is not grammatical. (As with most "why" questions, there is no genuine answer to the "why": I can only lay out the forms that are grammatical and show you the relationship between them).